# Context bounds in Traversable1

Tags: haskell

In [semigroupoids](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids) package I found the following definition:

```
class (Foldable1 t, Traversable t) => Traversable1 t where
  traverse1 :: Apply f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
  sequence1 :: Apply f => t (f b) -> f (t b)

  sequence1 = traverse1 id
  traverse1 f = sequence1 . fmap f
```

Why are the context bounds set to `Apply` (an `Applicative` without `pure`) and not to `Functor`? Obviously you need to overwrite one of the definitions, so is this impossible with "just" a `Functor`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a slightly tightened definition of a `Traversable`---all `Traversable1`s are `Traversable`, but not visa versa. For many (many) more details on why `Traversable`s need `Applicative`s, it's worth taking a look at [Applicative Programming with Effects](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html) perhaps. Gesturally, if you just had a `Functor` it wouldn't be possible to "sequence" the effects of that functor should it contain many values since your "injection" function `(a -> f b)` is the only way to get `b`s and you can't `join` the layers of your `f`.

But, broadly, when you define `Traversable`s you only need to use the effect-free injection function, `pure`, for "default" values, which is exactly what `Traversable1` eliminates. That's why `NonEmpty` is an instance but `[]` isn't.

To make things concrete, consider these example instances for the identity functor, `Maybe`, `NonEmpty` lists, and regular `[]`.

```
newtype Id a = Id a
instance Functor Id where fmap f (Id a) = Id (f a)

instance Applicative Id where
  pure = Id
  (Id f) <*> (Id x) = Id (f x)
```

We only need a `Functor` instance here exactly because `Id` has only one element and no "default" branch—it's quite trivial.

```
instance Traversable Id where traverse inj (Id a) = Id <$> inj a
instance Traversable1 Id where traverse1 inj (Id a) = Id <$> inj a
```

We need `pure` for the "default" `Nothing` case of `Maybe` (which is only slightly more complex than `Id`).

```
instance Traversable Maybe where
  traverse _ Nothing = pure Nothing
  traverse inj (Just a) = Just <$> inj a
```

`instance Traversable1 Maybe` can't exist because `Maybe` has a default branch; we see this because we can't use `pure` if we only have an `Apply` constraint.

```
data NonEmpty a = NonEmpty a [a]

instance Functor NonEmpty where fmap f (NonEmpty a as) = NonEmpty (f a) (fmap f as)

instance Apply NonEmpty where
  (NonEmpty f fs) <.> (NonEmpty x xs) = NonEmpty (f x) (fs <*> xs)

instance Pointed NonEmpty where
  point a = NonEmpty a []

instance Applicative NonEmpty where
  (<*>) = (<.>)
  pure = point

instance Traversable NonEmpty where
  traverse inj (NonEmpty a as) = NonEmpty <$> inj a <*> (traverse inj a as)
```

and since we only used `(<*>)` and not `pure`, we can make this a `Traversable1` instance

```
instance Traversable1 NonEmpty where
  traverse1 inj (NonEmpty a []) = (`NonEmpty` []) <$> inj a
  traverse1 inj (NonEmpty a (b: bs)) = 
    (\a' (NonEmpty b' bs') -> NonEmpty a' (b': bs')) 
    <$> inj a 
    <.> traverse1 inj (NonEmpty b bs)
```

but this doesn't work for `[]` since we end up using `pure` for the "default" branch

```
instance Traversable [] where
  traverse _   []     = pure []
  traverse inj (x:xs) = (:) <$> inj x <*> traverse inj xs
```

---

*Edit:* Originally I had played fast and loose with my definition of `Traversable1 NonEmpty`. The current version actually works but is a lot harder on the eyes. Previously I tried `traversing` the inner list, which works in spirit because the `[]` in the second slot of `NonEmpty` has the first slot to help it, but that can't work directly since the inner list has an empty case `[]` which needs `pure`. Instead, we have to avoid that empty case by "stealing" the always existant `a` in the first position and then replacing it after the traverse.

That method (and datatype definition) is very similar to the versions used in the Semigroups and Semigroupoids libraries themselves and are useful since they can take advantage of library momentum behind regular `[]`, but if we define `NonEmpty` a little differently we can see that there's a great deal of parallelism between `Traversable` and `Traversable1`. The fact that a `Traversable1` instance can exist is truly a feature of the data type alone---the definitions are basically identical.

```
import Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Semigroup as Se
import Data.Traversable
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Semigroup.Foldable
import Data.Semigroup.Traversable
import Data.Functor.Apply
import Control.Applicative

-- For comparison
data List     a = Empty | List a (List     a)
data NonEmpty a = One a | Many a (NonEmpty a)

instance Functor NonEmpty where
  fmap f (One a) = One (f a)
  fmap f (Many a as) = Many (f a) (fmap f as)

instance Apply NonEmpty where
  (One f) <.> (One a)         = One (f a)
  (One f) <.> (Many a _)      = One (f a)
  (Many f _) <.> (One a)      = One (f a)
  (Many f fs) <.> (Many a as) = Many (f a) (fs <.> as)

instance Applicative NonEmpty where
  pure = One
  (<*>) = (<.>)

instance Foldable NonEmpty where
  foldMap f (One a) = f a
  foldMap f (Many a as) = f a <> foldMap f as

instance Foldable1 NonEmpty where
  foldMap1 f (One a) = f a
  -- Core distinction: we use the Semigroup.<> instead of the Monoid.<>
  foldMap1 f (Many a as) = f a Se.<> foldMap1 f as

instance Traversable NonEmpty where
  traverse inj (One a) = One <$> inj a
  traverse inj (Many a as) = Many <$> inj a <*> traverse inj as

instance Traversable1 NonEmpty where
  traverse1 inj (One a) = One <$> inj a
  traverse1 inj (Many a as) = Many <$> inj a <.> traverse1 inj as
```